# Why no tail() or head() method in List to get last or first element?

Tags: java, list

I recently had a discussion with a colleague why the List interface in Java doesn't have a `head()` and `tail()` method.

In order to implement such a functionality would have to write a wrapper that looked something like this:

```
public E head() {
 if (underlyingList == null || underlyingList.isEmpty())
  return null;
 
 return underlyingList.get(0);
}


public E tail() {
 if (underlyingList == null || underlyingList.isEmpty())
  return null;
 
 return underlyingList.get(underlyingList.size()-1);
}
```

I'm not aware of all List implementations but I assume that at least in LinkedList and ArrayList it should be pretty trivial to **get the last and first element** (constant time).

So the question is:

Is there a specific reason why it is not a good idea to provide a tail method to any List implementation?

Comment: There is no `element()` method in `java.util.List`. Are you talking about some other class/interface?

Comment: You're right the element() method is implemented Deque interface which is implemented in LinkedList

Comment: There is also `getFirst()` and `getLast()` in the `Deque` interface

Comment: As explained by others `head()` and `tail()` can be implemented trivially. But I want to caution you against the `return null` part -- don't do it unless you have very good reason.

Comment: `tail` traditionally should return the the list minus its head. That's what you get in any functional language.

Comment: @Renato is correct.  That is not a tail method.  The answers to this question that are saying "it's trivial" thus don't apply to tail, only head.

Comment: Downvoted question for confusing incorrect terminology. Please reword the question, replacing "head" with "last" (at least, this is the Haskell name for what's implemented here).

Comment: I'm sorry that this is confusing for you, but in the java api doc, the terms "head" and "tail" are used numerous times, so I guess for this context these are the right terms.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Java Collections Framework is written by Joshua Bloch. One of his API design principles is: **High power-to-weight ratio**.

`tail()` and `head()` can be implemented by `get()` and `size()`, so it's not necessary to add `tail()` and `head()` to a very general interface `java.util.List`. Once users use the methods, you don't have chance to remove them and you have to maintain these unnecessary methods forever. That's bad.

Comment: Thing is these methods are not unnecessary - functional style list handling is PITA without these.

Comment: Not just a PITA, it's much less useful. Let's say I have a lazy list and I want to get it's tail. What do I do? Also, in order to get the tail of a list I have to walk all of it to calculate the length. That's a lot of waste.

Comment: This sounds like the argument Oracle used for not having booleans in their database.

Answer (score 23):

The List inteface has `subList` which is almost `head` and `tail`. You can wrap it as follows

```
public List head(List list) {
    return list.subList(0, 1);
}

public List tail(List list) {
    return list.subList(1, list.size());
}
```

**Edit**

Following the answer by @Pablo Grisafi, here is a Java quick sort implementation - not generic and not efficient. As expected `head()` should return an element  - not list.

```
public class QSort {

    public static List<Integer> qsort(List<Integer> list) {
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            return list;
        } else {
            return merge(
                    qsort(lesser
                            (head(list), tail(list))),
                    head(list),
                    qsort(greater(
                            head(list), tail(list)))
            );
        }
    }

    private static Integer head(List<Integer> list) {
        return list.get(0);
    }

    private static List<Integer> tail(List<Integer> list) {
        return list.subList(1, list.size());
    }

    private static List<Integer> lesser(Integer p, List<Integer> list) {
        return list.stream().filter(i -> i < p).collect(toList());
    }

    private static List<Integer> greater(Integer p, List<Integer> list) {
        return list.stream().filter(i -> i >= p).collect(toList());
    }

    private static List<Integer> merge(List<Integer> lesser, Integer p, List<Integer> greater) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList(lesser);
        list.add(p);
        list.addAll(greater);

        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(qsort(asList(7, 1, 2, 3, -1, 8, 4, 5, 6)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't "head" return an element rather than a sublist? I.e. `public <T> T head(List<T> list) { return list.get(0); }`

Comment: You can do that too. This is probably in line with the common meaning of   `head` and `tail`

Comment: feel like adding a size() == 0 check: `return list.size() > 0 ? list.subList(0, 1) : new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Finally, someone knows what `tail()` is supposed to be.

Comment: @averasko, I don't think there is a valid way to define head() / tail() on an empty list

Comment: @DavidSoroko I think it's called `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: If you think that calling head / tail on empty list is exceptional, you are welcome to throw an exception. Note though, that many list processing idioms (especially recursive / functional) consider such situation perfectly valid.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to process a list recursively, which is often what head/tail are used for in functional programming, you can use an Iterator.

```
Integer min(Iterator<Integer> iterator) {
    if ( !iterator.hasNext() ) return null;
    Integer head = iterator.next();
    Integer minTail = min(iterator);
    return minTail == null ? head : Math.min(head, minTail);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, `List` doesn't have an `element` method. `LinkedList`, however, has `getFirst()` and `getLast()`, which do as you describe.

Comment: "Get last" isn't the same as "tail".

Comment: The question gets the definition of tail() wrong, and the answers reproduce that mistake.

Answer (score 2):

In my humble opinion, tail and head are more familiar with people with a functional background. When you start passing functions around, they are incredible useful, that's why most functional languages have them implemented and even have shortcut notation to refer to them, like in haskell or even in scala (even if it's not THAT functional, I know)
In the "(almost) everything is an object but methods are made in a procedural way" java world, when passing around functions is at least hard and always awkward, head/tail methods are not so useful.
For example, check this haskell implementation of quicksort:

```
quicksort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
quicksort []     = []
quicksort (p:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++ [p] ++ (quicksort greater)
    where
        lesser  = filter (< p) xs
        greater = filter (>= p) xs
```

It relies, among other things, on the ability to easily separate head and tail, but also on being able to filter a collection using a predicate. A java implementation (check http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html) looks totally different, it is way lower level, and doesn't rely on separating head and tail.
Note: The next sentence is totally subjective and based on my personal experience and may be proven wrong, but I think it's true:
Most algorithms in functional programming rely on head/tail, in procedural programming you rely on accessing an element in a given position

Comment: I had a shot at implementing the functional quicksort in Java in my answer. Not as concise as Haskell but doable.

Answer (score 2):

### `List` is `SequencedCollection`

Since Java 21 there is a [SequencedCollection](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431) interface, a superinteface for `List`. Among other it provides `getFirst()` and `getLast()` methods:

```
jshell> List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).getFirst() = 1
jshell> List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).getLast() = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

there are always choices one must make in good API design.  there are *lots* of methods that *could* be added to the API, however, you have to find the fine line between making the API usable for most people and making it too cluttered and redundant.  as it is, you can implement the tail method as you have shown in an efficient way for most List implementations, and LinkedList already has a getLast() method.

Comment: This answer copies the mistake in the question, which gives an incorrect definition of tail(). Tail means the list sans the head, not the last element of the list.

Comment: @LawrenceDol - seems like your issue is with the question, not this answer, since the answer addresses the question as asked.  your interpretation seems to be one of the two valid interpretations according to wikipedia: "The 'tail' of a list may refer either to the rest of the list after the head, or to the last node in the list."

Comment: @LawrenceDol - please remove your misguided downvote.

Answer (score 0):

[peekLast](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#peekLast%28%29) method is already defined in Deque interface.
 
Moreover, It's obligatory for deque to have such a functionality. So, there's no point to define it in List or any other interface.
It's just convenient to split the functionality. If you need random access then you should implement [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html). If you need to access the tail efficiently then you should implement [Deque](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html). You can easily implement both of them (LinkedList does this, actually).

Comment: This answer copies the mistake in the question, which gives an incorrect definition of tail(). Tail means the list sans the head, not the last element of the list.

Comment: @LawrenceDol your definition is not the only one. For example, check out javadoc for [Deque.peekLast](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#peekLast%28%29) `the tail of this deque, or null if this deque is empty`. Documents for Java collections define tail as the last element. Original question also uses this definition.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a List, to make it easier.
When you use recursion on a list you have to think like this...
The list has an head(the first element) and a tail(all the other elements except the head).
With recursion you need to do what you want on the head and then call the function on the tail, so that you always have a list with size = size - 1

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    list.add(11);
    list.add(12);
    list.add(0);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(11);
    
    System.out.println(countOccurrences(list, 11));
    
}



public static int countOccurrences(List<Integer> list, int n) {
    if (list.size() == 0) {//if list is empty return 0
        return 0;
    }else {
        if(list.get(0) == n) {//if head of list is equal to n add 1 and call the function on the tail of the list
            return 1 + countOccurrences(list.subList(1, list.size()), n);
        }else {//else if it's not equal to n call the function on the tail of the list without adding 1
            return countOccurrences(list.subList(1, list.size()), n);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get those on Stream which is available on list:

head

```
myList.stream().findFirst() // Optional<T>, return empty for empty list
```

tail (traditional meaning)

```
myList.stream().skip(1).collect(toList()) // or don't collect & continue with a Stream
```

last (possibly dangerous if the list is infinite!):

```
myList.stream().reduce((a,b) -> b) // Optional<T>, return empty for empty list
```

Answer (score -1):

`head()` is provided via list.iterator().next(), list.get(0), etc.

It is only reasonable to provide tail() if the list is doubly linked with a tail pointer, or based on an array, etc., Neither of these aspects is specified for the List interface itself. Otherwise it could have O(N) performance.

Comment: This answer also reproduces the mistake in the question, which gives the incorrect definition of tail.  A tail functions returns the list without the head, so tail is actually ideally suited for a singly-linked list, not an array or doubly-linked list.

Comment: @Sigmax This answer answers the question that was actually asked, using  the same definitions that the OP used. I do not see the point of stating that he asked the wrong question, or of criticizing answers that answer it.