# Im wondering if there 's Head- and Tail-methods in Ruby or Ruby on Rails (framework)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just wondering if there's something similar in Ruby or RnR?

This post: [Why no tail() or head() method in List to get last or first element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568819/why-is-there-no-tail-and-head-method-in-the-java-list)
 talks about this about Java but I'm wondering the same thing but in Ruby or RnR.

Thanks for yr time!

Comment: What do you expect the `tail` method to return? The last element of a collection or the whole collection except its head?

Comment: @toro2k `tail` is usually everything except the `head`. If you want the last element, you use should call/define the method `last`. That linked Java question is confusing though, as the `tail` method there just returns the last element.

Comment: @tolgap That's the point, what `tail` means for OP is not clear at all.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is one possiblity:

```
head, *tail = args
```

It uses the Ruby splat operator.

Example:

```
args = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
head, *tail = args
head
# => 1
tail
# => [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: There is no need to splat `args` for it is already an array, `head, *tail = args` will do what you expect.

Comment: @tolgap Nice one! but that 'Tail' is mutable right? what If I want to keep running this for the next loop, this 'tail' wont be immutable right? To make things immutable in Ruby, it's too much work I guess :-(

Comment: @YoniGeek the `tail` variable is definitely mutable yeah, but it was not part of your question for it to be immutable though.

Comment: @tolgap that's correct! hey listen how would u do it if the 'tail' variable has to be immutable?

Answer (score 2):

The ruby array supports [first](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-first) and [last](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-last). Similarly `ActiveRecord` exposes the same methods for querying a database.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is nothing like that in `ruby` core lib or standard lib. But if you like functional style, you can implement one yourself and avoid monkey patching like this:

```
def head(n)
  n.to_a[0]
end

def tail(n)
  n.to_a[1..-1]
end
```

`to_a` is necessary if you want to support both array and enumerable. So you can call it like this:

```
>> head [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
=> 1
>> tail [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
=> [2, 3, 4, 5]
>> head 1..10
=> 1
>> tail 1..10
=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of ActiveRecord, you can use first and last:

```
Unit.first(5)
-> Unit Load (5.3ms)  SELECT `units`.* FROM `units` LIMIT 5
Unit.last(5)
-> Unit Load (1.7ms)  SELECT `units`.* FROM `units` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Or, an array (list):

```
units.first(5) # first 5
units[0,5]    # first 5
units[0..4]   # first 5
units.last(5) # last 5
units[-5,5]   # last 5
units[-5..-1] # last 5
```