# Java LinkedList iterator: Remove current element and all elements after it

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Theoretically, a LinkedList allows you to easily remove the tail of the list in constant time, by simply setting the removed reference to null.

In practice, how does Java's LinkedList let you do this?

For example:

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = linkedList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  if (iterator.next() % 2 == 0) {
    iterator.removeAllAfterThisPoint(); // how can we do this?
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all the example you have posted is wrong. `someList.iterator()` returns an `Iterator<E>` which is your case would be an `Iterator<Integer>` assuming that the list holds integers. Also your question is not very clear. You want to basically remove all elements after which point?

Comment: Remove all elements after any point in constant time, like a linked list lets you do.

e.g. with a list like 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 you can remove 3 -> 4 from the list by simply setting the `next` reference on 2 to null.

Comment: Bluntly: the API *doesn't* let you do this.  It's not supported the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you are trying to remove all the elements from the `LinkedList` after the first even number. My solution is to get the index at which the even number occurs and use the `subList(fromIndex, toIndex)` to remove all the elements after `toIndex`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 7, 9, 2, 4, 5, 17));
        ListIterator<Integer> iterator = list.listIterator();
        int toIndex = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (iterator.next() % 2 == 0) {
                toIndex = iterator.nextIndex();
                break;
            }
        }
        list = list.subList(0, toIndex);
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Input:

```
3
7
9
2
4
5
17
```

Output:

```
3
7
9
2
```

Comment: Right, but doesn't that take O(n) time on a LinkedList? Isn't one feature of a LinkedList that we can remove a specified tail of the list in constant time?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately we don't have methods in the Java `LinkedList` API to do what you are saying.

Comment: Check this answer as wells as the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081299/3888766